# Haughpagh.. WinTV HVR-950Q with Raspbmc?

Tags: raspbian, raspbmc

Will the WINTV HVR-950Q PVR ATSC Tuner work in the USA with OTA reception on RaspBMC?
Anyone have it working?

Comment: Doubtful, unless you have a way to connect that to the GPIO (would take *quite* a bit of wiring and programming the drivers). That is a PC expansion card, so AFAIK, unless you have an adapter (to USB), I'm doubtful. Would be very cool if you could get it to work though!

Comment: That model is a usb stick.  Maybe I got the model wrong, but the one I was looking at Amazon has usb on one side and cable or antenna connection on the other.

Comment: Oh, in that case I'm not sure. I can see what you have, @all: search for 'WINTV HVR-950Q PVR ATSC Tuner USB' it'll bring it right up. Image is at [http://www.hauppauge.com/pics/slider/hvr950q_slider.jpg](http://www.hauppauge.com/pics/slider/hvr950q_slider.jpg) and you can see it online.

Answer (score 3):

yes, it works out of box on raspbmc, external power is not required. I have setup with Asterisk, tvheadend, PVR storage on Time capsule.